# How to do security trimming in sharepoint 2013 rest api?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest, security-trimming

In my sp 2013, I am trying to do a rest api and get security trimmed results, when I try my url

```
_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Navigation')/items?$select=Comments,effectivebasepermissions&$filter=effectivebasepermissions/high%20gt%2032&$top=1000
```

I get back

```
<m:error><m:code>-2147024809, System.ArgumentException</m:code><m:message xml:lang="en-US">Column 'effectivebasepermissions' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.  /Lists/Navigation</m:message></m:error>
```

Does anyone know whats wrong?

Comment: Results should be security trimmed for you already in all of the web services, REST or SOAP, you don't need to ask for it.

Comment: But here https://chrisstahl.wordpress.com/2014/06/30/getting-started-with-rest-in-sharepoint-2013-part-2/ it says `The result from a REST query are not security trimmed so if you want to display only the sites for which the users has access to`...

Comment: Theres also this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/a1d88bff-6a0a-41aa-ba0b-291179a6a3b4/security-trimmed-snippet-and-script-editor-web-part

Comment: Trust me; if REST results were **not** security trimmed CNN, Fox and Saturday Night Live would report nothing else.

Comment: Does `effectivebasepermissions/high` exist? Make sure it is the internal name. Another thing `/` is used in lookup column. If `effectivebasepermissions` is a lookup column, then you must expand it.